# How to import custom data via XML, CSV, etc

Tags: customization, import

We have about 10 years of custom blog-style, databased content that we want to import into a clean install of Wordpress. There doesn't seem to be an importer plugin that works with custom databsed content so has anyone done a direct INSERT into the Wordpress tables to achieve this? I can easily create custom INSERT statements for each of our custom rows. Does someone know what tables need to be touched for this or is there an easier or more conventional way to do this? Thanks

Comment: We made a plugin called WP All Import that can do this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-all-import/

Answer (score 1):

To insert i a wordpress way would be to use [**wp_insert_post()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) function which handles the actual database insertion.

And i have used a [**CSV 2 POST Free Data Importer plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-2-post/) before on version 3.0 and as far as i know it should work with 3.1.1